# Re-center Modal Popup with Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a modal popup that initially shows some content but expands a div if a checkbox is selected. The modal expands correctly but doesn't recenter unless you scroll up or down. Is there a javascript event I can tack on to my javascript function to recenter the entire modal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what it is:

```
$find('ModalPopupExtenderClientID')._layout();
```

For example:

```
$find('detailsPopUpExtenderId')._layout();
```

and in aspx:

```
<ccl:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="MyPopUpExtender" TargetControlID="pop" PopupControlID="PopUp" BehaviorID="detailsPopUpExtenderId" BackgroundCssClass="ModalBackground" />
```

`BehaviorID` being the property where to set the clientside id.

Comment: Works well, thanks. I used the ClientID property in code to get the full client id.

Comment: You can stablish the property `BehaviourId` on the `ModalPopupExtender` control, to do that without think on the ClientID `$find('bahaviour id')._layout();`. Anyway, good trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Be careful that this isn't tied to the resize event of the window.  If it is, your recentering could trigger a resize event in IE, which would cause an infinte loop.

If it is tied to the resize event, allow 1 or 2 resize events to occur, but then ignore the rest. (I say 2, because in IE, a "restore" event on the window will trigger at least 2 resize events (3 in IE6).

Answer (score 0):

Whatever event you have bound to the scrolling to get it to re-center, bind that event to the checkbox/div expanding event as well (or call it from within the other event).  Hard to say more without seeing some code.