# Asp.net modalPopupExtender repositioning

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modalpopupextender

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Re-center Modal Popup with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176831/re-center-modal-popup-with-javascript)

By default, when using a modalPopupExtender from the ajaxControlToolkit - it is repositioned in the centre of the browser when the browser window is resized.

I'm guessing this is some kind of javascript hooked into a window.resize method?

I am altering the size of the panel associated with the extender, which puts the popup off-centre.

Is there a way of firing this 'centre' operation directly, achieving the same result of resizing the actual browser?

Cheers! :D

Edit: still looking for any bright ideas! I've been browsing through the toolkit sourcecode as well as the source pages I create (and the javascript they use) finding many references to _layout, _onLayout and other such functions but I'm still stuck :(

Comment: aha! <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176831/re-center-modal-popup-with-javascript"> thanks go to Luke! </a> Sorry for the duplicate question (and I've been searching for days!)

Answer (score 2):

This solution helped me: http://radderz.me.uk/2009/10/clientside-repositioning-a-modal-popup-extender/

It uses Jquery. You can download it here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js. Then reference it on your page as you would to a normal JS. Ex., `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Link no longer works...